# What is meant by "rotation about an axis that passes through a lattice point"?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography, lattices

I am currently studying *Introduction to Solid State Physics*, 8th edition, by Charles Kittel. In the section **Fundamental Types of Lattices** of chapter 1, the author says the following:

> Crystal lattices can be carried or mapped into themselves by the lattice translations $\mathbf{T}$ and by various other symmetry operations. A typical symmetry operation is that of rotation about an axis that passes through a lattice point.

It's unclear to me what is meant by "rotation about an axis that passes through a lattice point". In doing research, I found [this](http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/symm1/rotate2.htm) page, but I'm not completely sure that this is referring to the same phenomenon. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this. I would especially appreciate pictures depicting this, as well as the mathematics itself.

Comment: yes normal rotation about an axis, say, by 90 or 120 degrees, etc. but with the restriction that any symmetry operations causes the structure to be _indistinguishable_ from that before the operation occurred.

Comment: @porphyrin So exactly as is described here http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/symm1/rotate2.htm ?

Comment: yes, same is true of all symmetry operations

Comment: @porphyrin Ok, thanks for the clarification.